# Computing sectional curvature of Hyperbolic space

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, curvature, hyperbolic-geometry

On the unit disk $|x|<1$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, let's give a hyperbolic metric
$$
g_{ij}=\frac{4\delta_{ij}}{(1-|x|^2)^2}.
$$
I want to compute sectional curvature $K(\partial_i\wedge\partial_j)$ by computing it in the coordinate expressions, but somehow I cannot get the correct answer. Please let me know where I got wrong.

First let me compute the first derivatives of $g_{ij}$ :
$$
g_{ij,l}=\frac{16\delta_{ij}x^l}{(1-|x|^2)^3}.
$$

Then the Christoffel symbols are computed as :
$$
\Gamma_{ij}^k=\frac{1}{2}g^{kl}(g_{il,j}+g_{jl,i}-g_{ij,l})
=\frac{2}{1-|x|^2}(\delta_{ik}x^j+\delta_{jk}x^i-\delta_{ij}x^k).
$$

From this, we can compute the $R_{ijij}$:(now $i,j$ are distinct and fixed)
$$
R_{ijij}=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{ij}g_{ij}+\partial_{ij}g_{ij}-\partial_{ii}g_{jj}-\partial_{jj}g_{ii})+g_{jp}(\Gamma_{ii}^{m}\Gamma_{jm}^{p}-\Gamma_{ij}^{m}\Gamma_{im}^{p})
=\frac{-1}{2}(\partial_{ii}g_{jj}+\partial_{jj}g_{ii})+\frac{4\delta_{jp}}{(1-|x|^2)^2}(\Gamma_{ii}^{m}\Gamma_{jm}^{p}-\Gamma_{ij}^{m}\Gamma_{im}^{p})
$$

For $\partial_{jj}g_{ii}$, we get
$$
\partial_{jj}g_{ii}=\partial_j 16\frac{x^j}{(1-|x|^2)^3}=16\frac{1}{(1-|x|^2)^3}+16\frac{6(x^j)^2}{(1-|x|^2)^4}=16\frac{1-|x|^2+6(x^j)^2}{(1-|x|^2)^4}.
$$

And for the Christoffel symbols part, we compute:
$$
\Gamma_{ii}^m=\frac{2}{1-|x|^2}(2\delta_{im}x^i-x^m),
\Gamma_{jm}^j=\frac{2}{1-|x|^2}(x^m),
\Gamma_{ij}^m=\frac{2}{1-|x|^2}(\delta_{im}x^j+\delta_{jm}x^i),
\Gamma_{im}^j=\frac{2}{1-|x|^2}(\delta_{jm}x^i-\delta_{im}x^j).
$$
Hence
$$
\Gamma_{ii}^{m}\Gamma_{jm}^{j}-\Gamma_{ij}^{m}\Gamma_{im}^{j}=\frac{4}{(1-|x|^2)^2}(2(x^i)^2-|x|^2-(x^i)^2+(x^j)^2)=\frac{4}{(1-|x|^2)^2}(-|x|^2+(x^i)^2+(x^j)^2).
$$
Note that we changed $p$ into $j$ by $\delta_{jp}$ multiplied in front of them.

Combining these results, we conclude that
$$
R_{ijij}=\frac{16}{(1-|x|^2)^4}(-1+|x|^2-3(x^i)^2-3(x^j)^2-|x|^2+(x^i)^2+(x^j)^2)=\frac{16}{(1-|x|^2)^4}(-1-2(x^i)^2-2(x^j)^2).
$$

Then
$$
K(\partial_i\wedge\partial_j)=\frac{R_{ijij}}{g_{ii}g_{jj}}=-1-2(x^i)^2-2(x^j)^2\not\equiv -1,
$$
contradicting the constant sectional curvature $=-1$ property of the Hyperbolic space.

Where did I do wrong?

$$
$$
Added: I found out that I can get the correct answer by using the following formula for the (3,1)-curvature tensor :
$$
R_{ijk}^l=\partial_j \Gamma_{ik}^l-\partial_i \Gamma_{jk}^l+\Gamma_{ik}^{m}\Gamma_{jm}^{l}-\Gamma_{jk}^{m}\Gamma_{im}^{l}
$$
while I was using different formula for (4,0)-curvature tensor above(which is given by the book "The Ricci Flow in Riemannian Geometry" by Andrews and Hopper, section 2.7.4).
$$
R_{ijkl}=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{jk}g_{il}+\partial_{il}g_{jk}-\partial_{ik}g_{jl}-\partial_{jl}g_{ik})+g_{lp}(\Gamma_{ik}^{m}\Gamma_{jm}^{p}-\Gamma_{jk}^{m}\Gamma_{im}^{p})
$$

I tried to verify the second formula from the first one, but I get the extra terms involving first derivatives of $g$, namely $g^{pq}_{,i}, g_{pq,j}$ etc. So I guess that the second formula is incorrect. Am I right about this point?

Comment: I suggest computing $R_{ijkl}$ first, and then set $k=i$, $l=j$ only at the end.

Comment: Or use an orthonormal moving frame to find the curvature components with respect to the frame and use that to find the curvature components with respect to the coordinate vector fields. This is by far the easiest way to do the calculation.

Comment: @Deane Thank you for your suggestion! Can you also verify the added claim about the (4,0)-curvature tensor formula? Thank you in advance.